# Create an html element for each value in a scala array using play 2.4.6

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4

Quite new to Scala. I am trying to create a web page which loads buttons based on the values of arrays, so I don't have to create a new button element in the template for each button. I am using Scala and Play 2.4.6.

I figured I would pass the arrays to template.scala.html like this:

```
@(buttonGroup1: Array)(buttonGroup2: Array)(buttonGroup3: Array)
```

I am just not sure how I would iterate through the arrays to generate all of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a button type, something like this:

```
case class Button(id: String, text: String, ...)
```

And then use it in your view like this:

```
@(buttonGroup1: Seq[Button], buttonGroup2: Seq[Button], buttonGroup3: Seq[Button])

@for(button <- buttonGroup1) {
  <button id="@button.id">@button.text</button>
}

...
```

And so on. Then call the view like this:

```
val content = views.html.buttons(Seq(Button("foo", "bar")), ..., ...)
```

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTemplates